# 「回答ではない」と書かれた回答をどう扱うべきか

Tags: 討議, 回答の仕方

表題の通り、回答欄に「回答ではありません」と書かれた投稿が (同じユーザーによって) 何度かされています。

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/96695
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/94023

個人的にはそれぞれの質問内容について詳しくないので、これら回答の評価はしかねるところですが、全くのデタラメを書いているわけでは無さそうです。しかし、「回答ではありません」の宣言を受けてなのか、マイナス評価になりがちのようです。

前提として、スタックオーバーフローでは「質問」「回答」「コメント」でそれぞれ明確な使い分けをしています。
読み手としては「回答欄は回答を書くところなので、回答以外のものは書かないでください」としか言いようがありません。

一方、回答側として考えると一部は分からなくもない部分があります。例えば「実際には実行して試してないけど」や「質問者に試してもらいたい内容があるけど、コメント欄では書ききれないので」など、完全な回答と言うには自信が無いけど、いったん回答として投稿するケースです。

ただしそれらの場合なら、「回答でない」の代わりにありのままの事情を書くとか、回答でない以上は多少のマイナス票は受け入れるべき (または回答を後から修正する、別回答を投稿する) と感じます。

件の投稿では「役立つ回答として見られるのは困るので "回答ではない" と書いている」 (=プラス評価はされたくない？)一方、「指摘も無しにマイナス票を入れられるのはなぜなのか」とも言っており、評価に困るところです。

---

「サイトのルールに思うところがあるなら、メタで話し合いましょう」と何度か提案していますが、参加する意思が無いようです。このような投稿をコミュニティとしてどう扱うべきでしょうか？

# 個人的には、マイナス評価が嫌なら「回答ではない」の一文が不要だと思いますが、一定の意思を持って記載しているようなので第三者が勝手に編集するようだとそれはそれで拗れそうです。

Answer (score 8):

### 「回答ではない」と書かれた回答をどう扱うべきか

その回答が**本当に回答ではないならば、削除のためのモデレーションが行われるべき**だと考えます。これには、質問に対してさらに質問を返すような回答や、自己解決した旨だけが書かれ、具体的な解決策が述べられていない回答などが含まれます。また、「回答ではない（あるいはその可能性がある）」と回答に書かざるを得ないような不明確な質問であれば、その質問自体が改善される必要があるとして**クローズされるべき**です。たとえば、回答者が十人十色の仮定を置いた回答をしなければならないケースでは、質問自体が改善されなければ議論が発散してしまい、有益性を欠いたQ&Aになってしまうかもしれません。

一方で回答として十分な品質ならば、モデレーションによって**削除するかどうかは慎重に判断されるべき**です。ここでいう品質とは、回答が質問に答えているかどうかであって、技術的な真偽や有益性は重要ではありません。それらは投票によって評価されるべきです。誤った回答が単に削除されるのではなく、マイナスにスコアリングされた状態で残っていれば、Q&Aの将来の読み手にバッドプラクティスを伝える効果もあるでしょう。また、「その疑問に対する答えはここでは得られないだろう」や「現状ではそれは未解決の問題です」といった趣旨の回答も、その論拠が提供されていれば質問に対して十分に答えているものと考えます。

ただし、その投稿が回答として機能するにも関わらず、「回答ではない」と書かれていることによって、**読み手の判断に錯誤を与える可能性**があります。そのような理由でのマイナス投票は正当なものだと考えます。

本質的には『「回答ではない」と書かれた回答』全般に対する対処法を議論するのは難しいと考えます。なぜなら、質問の内容によって回答に求められる具体性や有益性も変化するため、どうしても個別の事例で議論せざるを得ないことが多く、「回答ではない」と書かれている事実だけでなく、**その他の文脈も含めた議論が必要**になるためです。

すべてのケースを包括的に議論すると発散してしまう恐れがあるため、質問文やリンク先の実例を踏まえて、私が本質問で問題になっていると考えた次の4つの事例に関して取り上げます。これらのいずれのケースでも私の基本的な趣旨は上述したとおりですが、もう少し意見の詳細を書き加えたいと思います。

- 「実際には実行して試していない」回答
- 「役立つ回答として見られるのは困るので "回答ではない" と書いている」回答
- 「質問者に試してもらいたい内容」を述べている回答
- 既存の回答を評価・要約する回答

### 「実際には実行して試していない」回答

試していないからただちに回答ではない、と結論づけられることはないと考えます。

それは実際には正しく動くかもしれませんし、動かなくとも十分に意図が伝わる内容かもしれません。質問で提示された問題を解決するための道筋を示せているのであれば、読み手に対して十分な有益性をもたらすでしょう。

さきほども述べた通り、技術的に不正確であったり、完全に間違った答えであったとしても、それが質問に答えようとしているのであれば、回答として成立しているものと考えます。**技術的な真偽は回答に対する投票で決めるべき**です。その投票を受けて回答者本人が回答を削除するのは自由ですが、モデレータやユーザが削除したり、削除するように働きかけたりするのは過剰なモデレーションにあたると思います。

### 「役立つ回答として見られるのは困るので "回答ではない" と書いている」回答

回答者本人が困るかどうかは関係なく、有益な回答は評価されプラス票が集まるべきです。

もちろん、「回答が想定よりも評価されて困るから回答を削除する」という行動をとるのは、回答者本人の自由です。しかし、もし回答者の意向に従って回答の評価自体が左右されるのであれば、多くの参加者にとって有益なコンテンツを上位に表示しようとする、スタック・オーバーフローの評価システムそのものが崩壊してしまいます。そのような趣旨の要求が投稿者からなされたとしても、本サイトの趣旨からして許容できないことは明白です。

上でも述べた通り、「回答ではない」と明確に記載していることによりマイナス評価がなされることもあるでしょう。しかし、その一文のみで回答として不適切とされた上に、削除のモデレーションがされるほど致命的なものではないと考えます。

### 「質問者に試してもらいたい内容」を述べている回答

これは「何を試してもらいたいのか」により結論が変化すると思います。

たとえば「Xというエラーが出るのを直したい」という質問に対して「原因を絞り込むためにソフトウェアYのバージョンを確認してください」という、「質問者に試してもらいたい内容」を回答をしたとします。これは直接的に問題を解決する方法を述べているのではなく、トラブルシューティングの一過程で実施してほしい作業を助言しているだけです。そのため回答ではなくコメントとして投稿されるべきで、コメント化や削除のモデレーションが行われる可能性が高いと思います。

一方で、「その問題を解決するために、この方法を試してみてください」という趣旨の回答は、質問への直接的な回答を提供しており、たとえ実際には問題を解決しなかったとしても、回答として成立していると考えます。もし質問に何らかの不備があり、回答者が様々な仮定を行ったうえで回答しなければならない場合は、質問がクローズされ、改善されるのを待つのがあるべきプロセスだと思います。しかし、質問者が十分に情報を提供しているなかでも、真の原因が絞り込めないことは往々にしてあります。そのような場面で回答者が各々の経験的知識から導き出した仮説を回答として投稿することは**ナレッジの蓄積という観点からも有益**だと見なせるのではないでしょうか。

言うまでもなく、「この方法を試してください」とだけ回答するよりも、なぜそれを試してほしいのか、質問文の状態から何を変えたのかを説明し、回答により説得力を持たせるほうが、ナレッジの蓄積という観点からは好ましいでしょう。しかし、これができていないから回答ではないというのは厳しすぎる基準だと感じますし、これをもってマイナス投票がされることはあっても、削除してしまうのは行き過ぎたモデレーションになると考えます。

### 既存の回答を評価・要約する回答

すでに何度も述べていることですが、このような種類の回答についても同様に、質問や回答の文脈により受け入れられるかが変化すると考えています。

他の回答が提示したコードを単に並べ立てるだけの回答でも、便利な要約と言えなくはないかもしれません。しかし、それが新しい情報や視点を提供するものではないならば、回答としては低い品質と見なされても不思議ではありません。ただしそれがモデレーションによって削除されるかどうかは、個別に判断されなければならないと思います。

一方で、「以下のように性能を評価した結果から、Xという条件のもとでは、Yの手法がより適切です」という形式で、一方の回答がもう一方よりある視点では優れているとする論拠を示す回答は、回答として成立しているといえる可能性が高いでしょう。なぜなら他の回答者が示さなかった、**より深い洞察を読者へ提供するため**です。スタック・オーバーフローのQ&Aモデルに立ち返れば、質問に投稿された回答は質問者だけのものではなく、将来にわたって同様の疑問を持った読者に向けて有益なことが望ましいはずです。数値計算のように、質問で明確に要求されていなくても、多くの読者にとって性能の評価が望まれている可能性が高いケースもあります。つまり、さまざまな回答が並ぶなかでそれらを要約し、その質問の文脈に沿った新しい視点を提供する回答であれば、回答として十分な品質だと考えます。そういった回答は、マイナス票が入れられる理由があったとしても、回答ではないとして一概に削除されるほど無益あるいは有害ではないと思います。

ただし、質問ではまったく求められておらず、かつ質問内容を取り巻く分野でも重視されていない評価指標を用いた評価は、無益なものと見なされマイナス票を投票されてしまうかもしれません。さらには削除されてしまう可能性もありますが、あくまでもそういったモデレーションは個別に判断された上で（微妙なケースはメタでの討議を経て）行われるべきです。

Answer (score 3):

タイトルがあいまいだったり、本文が散漫だったりということはこの件に限らず普通にあることです。書き込まれた内容が質問に対して役に立つものであるならば必要に応じて回答の体をなすように編集すればいいと思います。

Stack Overflowでは最初の回答者が完璧な回答を書かなければならないということはなく、一定のReputationがある人なら自由に編集ができるのでより良い形になるように編集すればいいです。

本当に回答ではなくまったく関係がなかったり役に立たない内容であるなら削除も妥当と考えます。

Answer (score 2):

投稿する以上は運用規約に合意しているとみなしてよくて、それでも「回答でない」と明示しちゃう以上はマイナスモデ喰らうのは事前に了解があるものとみなしてよい、んだと思います。オイラも [C++11にstd::stouiがないのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16470/) のような発言はしたことありますので「回答でない」けど回答欄使いたくなる気持ちはよくわかります。
# オイラは一応、できるだけ回答っぽくように配慮するようにはしている。

で、どう取り扱うべきかなんですが、<del>シスオペ</del>モデレータが出張るからもめるのであって、ほおっておきましょう。一般読者からマイナスモデがいっぱいついて沈められちゃうまで待っておけばよいのです。

理由の指摘なしにマイナスモデってなぜ？はオイラも思うところがありますが、しょせんはただの掲示板、ここでマイナスされようがプラスされようが収入が増減するとか税率が増減するとかもないし、少なくともオイラはキニシナイ。
# オイラ以外の人が気にするかどうかはその人次第っス。

この場 (SO/MSE) が気に入らないのなら来なくなるだろうし、来て発言する以上は規約通りに評価されるだけの話で、それが気に入らないなら以下この文をループ。

Comment: 今回の件で「モデレータが出張る」の部分は具体的に何を指していますでしょうか？
モデレータの一人がコメントしていることですか？

Comment: 「ほおっておきましょう」に賛成で、私はモデレーター権限で何か行うつもりは有りません。
（メインサイトの回答にメタ的な議論を書き込んでいる点は、程度により対処が必要になるかも知れませんが、これもまずは一般ユーザーの権限で編集できる範囲です）

Comment: オイラの意図は「モデレータのひとがコメントしていること」です。一般ユーザーとしてコメントしたつもりであっても、コメント者にモデレータ権限があるだけでダイヤマークが自動的についちゃう様子ですが、それをもって「モデレータが強権発動している」と読んぢゃう読者はいると思われます。ダイヤマークつかないようにコメントできるんでしたっけ？（は別Q&Aにすべきかも）

Comment: 「ダイヤマークつかないようにコメント」はできないです。
私もこれは良くないことだと思っていて、 [立候補時にも最後に触れました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=nomination#post-95030) 。
（ただ私は、これをもってしてモデレーター就任中にコメントを控えるつもりも無いです。権限をちらつかせることの無いように注意は必要ですね。留意します。）

Answer (score 2):

「どう扱うべきか」の主語が各ユーザーなのかモデレーターなのかサイトなのか。
議論の対象が一般論なのか特定の投稿そのものなのか投稿したユーザーの行動なのか。
いろいろなことが書かれている上自身の見解が示されないこともあってゴールがわからないです。

結果、回答みても「で？」という感想にしかなりません。
個々の回答に問題があるという意味ではなく、ポイントがバラバラなので結論としてまとまらない。

この状態で「回答ではないと書かれた投稿に対するコミュニティの見解」をくみ出されてもな、としか思えません。

それは内容によってはモデレータ権限の是非の根拠にもなるのですから、その点でも自身の見解を示さずに意見だけ募るのには問題があります

Comment: 結論としてまとまらないという問題意識は理解します。ただ、私は回答を読んだ結果モデレーター権限を使わないという自身の判断に確信が持てましたので、有意義だったと思います。 1.《主語》に関して。例えば、モデレーター権限で何かすべきという話になれば、一般ユーザーの行動としては通報が必要です。このように相互に関係していますので、「主語」は「サイト」だとして、まとめて考えてはどうでしょうか。 2.《一般論なのか特定の投稿》なのかに関して。これは一貫してメタサイトで議論が錯綜しがちです。議論の必要は個別の事例から生じるのですが、原則的な理想も考えないと、個別の事例に対処できませんし、難しい所だと思います。 3.《自身の見解》の不足に関して。 確かに、権限者であれば自身の見解を明かにすべきです。 しかし、モデレーターは通報を受ければ、自身の見解の有無に関わらず対処しなければなりません。 その可能性を考えると、自身の見解を持つ前に広く意見を求めることにもご理解いただきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

この投稿自体も回答ではないのですが、私の考えは774RRさんの見解に近いです。
質問も回答もQ&Aの蓄積に害するものならマイナスモデされて沈められればいいと思います。逆に、（質問者への回答とはならないものの）同様のまたは類似する質問を抱える閲覧者に有益なことであれば、受け入れられると思います。

私も[「std::mapの初期化を綺麗にしたい」への回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/91792/4236)では、質問文には「C++17でお願いします」とありましたが、他の閲覧者は条件が異なることもあると考え、C++20での情報も記載しました。この投稿は閲覧者にはきちんと評価されたようで +4 となっています。

この件が原因かよくわかりませんが、私はこの質問者に恨まれており、幾度となく不当マイナスモデを受けています（モデレーター or システムにより復旧してもらっています）。
被害妄想かもしれませんが、本題の「回答ではない」との投稿の仕方も私への当てつけめいたものを感じなくもありません。

Answer (score 0):

おそらくほとんどの人が重要視されていないように見られますが、ヘルプ記事にはこう書かれています。

[スタック・オーバーフロー > ヘルプセンター > 権限 マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

> #### マイナス投票とは?
>
> マイナス投票とは、「マイナス票の投票」とも呼ばれ、どの質問および回答が最も役に立たないかをコミュニティが示す方法です。
>
> #### どんな時にマイナス投票したらいいですか?
>
> **はなはだしくずさんな、まったく努力していない投稿、または明らかに、そして危険なほど不正確な回答を見つけたら、マイナス票を使用してください。**

> #### マイナス投票するとどうなりますか?
>
> 途中省略 **回答へのマイナス投票は、軽々しく行ってほしくないため、無料ではありません。**

> #### マイナス投票に代わるものは?
>
> 途中省略 **マイナス票はコミュニケーションや編集の代わりを意図するものではありません。**

> - **何かが間違っている場合はコメントを残すか投稿を編集して訂正してください。**

タイトル以外の太字は引用者による強調

---

対象の回答者は何かのこだわりや癖の強い人のようですが、上記ガイドラインに抵触してマイナス投票するほどでは無いような気がします。
ガイドラインや本人が言及しているように先ずはコメントを残してみることをお勧めします。

---

**@mjy さんのコメントに対して：**

今回紹介されている2つの例だと、最初の方は質問へのコメントに書かれた内容を実際にコードにしたということなので、回答の方にも最初にコメントの内容を重複して記述するか、コメントの方は消して回答に一本化するよう促すのが良いと思われます。実際に質問者さんは、その回答が有用だとして承認されている訳ですし。

2つ目の方は、強いて言えば「何のために何故」そうした回答記事を書いたのかをもう少し補足する内容を追記して欲しいと促した方が良いとは思います。
「回答ではありません」が太字で目立ちすぎている感じですが、「ちなみに」程度の柔らかい言葉で本筋では無いことをあらかじめことわっておけばマイナス投票やコメントの応酬はなかったかもしれません。

Comment: 一般論として完全に賛成いたします。
ただ、今回の件は既にコメントで「回答ではない」について言及されており、その上で回答者さんが明確に「回答ではない」という表現を変更するつもりが無いと返答しています。
この場合、どう考えるべきでしょうか。

Comment: @mjy さん、該当の回答者さんはこのサイトに現れた頃からの経緯や自身のプロフィールに書かれた内容からして相当にこだわりや癖のある人のようですが、時々現れるもっとぶっ飛んだ人よりは話が通じると思われます。そういう情報を踏まえると大々的に「回答ではない」と書いてこだわることに、私自身は「さもありなん」と共感を覚える方です。私自身が同様にコメントや指摘の無い匿名の陰に隠れたマイナス投票を多数受けているので。しかも何カ月も経過した後にコミュニティbotで上位に晒され注目を促されたときにマイナス投票されるという何が何だか分からない状況も複数経験しています。「回答ではない」と書く真意が何かは分かりませんが、私自身の感想から言えば、「回答では無いことを理由に指摘やコメントの無いマイナス投票をする人がいるらしい」し、それは自分にとっては不快だから「最初から回答では無いことを明記しておけばそういうマイナス投票や無駄な指摘は減らせるのでは？」と考えてもおかしくは無いと思います。ただし現状ではそれは逆効果でマイナス投票を引き寄せる結果になっていますが。

Comment: なるほど。そういった思いの結果というケースも有り得るのですね。
ただ、今回は違うようです。
確認しましたが、今回の回答者さんの回答には、ずっとマイナス票など入っていなかったのです。
[ある回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/92420/3054) に最初から「回答ではありません」とあり、そこで初めてマイナス票が入れられました。
そして、「マイナス票」の理由が知りたいという訴えには複数の方が答えてきました。
時系列がこうですので、「理由の解らないマイナス票が入る」 → 「回答ではないと書いてみる」という因果ではなかったです。

Comment: 最近の回答はそんなに変な扱いは無いようでしたが、しばらく前には結構ありましたよ。それがプロフィールの概要に書かれた記述につながっていて、「回答ではない」の強調になっている可能性があるかもしれません。

Comment: 「変な扱い」のあった回答をいくつか教えていただけますか？ （モデレータへの通報という形でもOKです）

Comment: 該当の人の[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/54957/dameo?tab=answers)や[質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/54957/dameo?tab=questions)でマイナス票の付いた物とか。今見るとそんなに数は無いですね、クローズされた質問でのやり取りが強烈な印象だったので大袈裟に覚えていたのか、あるいはプロフィールの概要に書かれているように本当に強烈なものは削除されて見えなくなっているのかもしれません。

Comment: マイナス票の付いている回答ですが、私が上で挙げた「回答ではありません」が始まった回答までは無いです。
その後も、「回答ではありません」と書いたもの以外ではマイナス票を受けていません。
少ないのではなく、本当に1件もないのです（削除済みも含めて）。
おっしゃる通り、特定の質問の印象が強かったのだと思います。